# Representing daily data in an appropriate chart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, data-analysis

I am new to JFreeChart. I am using this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jfreechart/jfreechart_bar_chart.htm) for reference.

Let me explain background of my requirement. Suppose I have business data as follows.

[image: example from tutorialspoint]

For this requirement, bar chart would look like this. (shown in one of the attached image)

[image: generated bar chart for given business data]

I understood this example; it is fairly easy one. Now I have to explain my requirement in the context of this example.
Lets suppose I want to capture the same data day wise ie. My business data would change on every day. 
For example attached business data is of Monday. likewise similar business data would come on Tuesday, Wednesday and so on.

How to represent such scenario in a chart? Which chart should I go for in order to represent data like this? I am using JFreeChart, but I am open to any new Java chart library.

I am suggested to create multiple bar chart for each day, but that would be last option.

Comment: in a post specified by you, there is no comparison done. it is just showing plain bar charts according to number of days in a month.

Comment: I need to show the comparison of day wise stats.

Comment: it will address my requirement.....! thanks trashgod

Comment: Glad to help. You might also look at a Orson Charts 3D. If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.